# Remove line under image in link in WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have tried to solve it with CSS by adding:

```
.image-link {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    border:0px !important;
    outline:none;
    border-width: 0px;
    outline-width:0px;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Also adding this on widget html:

```
<a href="https://www.mussarecords.cl" class="image-link">
```

thanks

Comment: Also adding this on widget html: <a href="link" class="image-link">

Comment: Learn to troubleshoot.  Are your styles being applied, when you use your browser's developer console to inspect the element in question?  If not, troubleshoot why - what are the _existing_ styles? I'm guessing your styles either are not loading, or else you have a specificity issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a style="background: none; text-decoration: none; box-shadow: none;" href="https://www.mussarecords.cl">click</a>
```

adding inline css works for me..i tested it..no need for external css

Comment: I added the code to the css but it did not work, thanks

Comment: i added the inline css..that works perfectly fine..take a look at my code now..replace your wideget html code with that

Comment: great..happy coding

Comment: This is a workaround, and does not get to the root of the problem, or solve the problem, or help the OP with future problems like this.